# Haskell: Meaning of `|`, `<-` and `->` in a single line

Tags: haskell

What is the meaning of expressions like this one? Taken from [here](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.15/yaml-0.11.0.0/src/Data.Yaml.Internal.html#decodeHelper).

```
case x of
    Left e
        | Just pe <- fromException e -> return $ Left pe
```

Is this pattern matching with guards and then mapping of the matched result? What is the name of the `->` syntax used here?

Comment: The `->` is part of the `case` statement you didn't include in the question.

Comment: Still, can't wrap my head around this. We can pattern match a `case` and then add more guarded subsequent matches? What is the structure of such expressions?

Comment: This is an example of a [pattern guard](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard). It happens to be a guard within a case expression here, but it also can be used with guards that are not part of a case expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a [pattern guard](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard). It's a bit like syntactic sugar for

```
case x of
    Left e -> case fromException e of
      Just pe -> return $ Left pe
```

except if the `Just pe` match fails, execution will automatically handed on to the next clause in the *outer* `case x of` switch.

Comment: I just realized I have no idea how the compiler actually desugars fall-through. Does it immediately define auxiliary functions?

Comment: I don't know; I always assumed that it basically unrolls the outer and inner fallbacks – but thinking about it, that code duplication would be quite haphazard.